# If $x^2 + 3x + 2 < 0$ and $ f(x) = x^2 – 3x + 2$, then find the correct inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

(A)  0 < f(x) < 6
      (B)  f(x) > 12
      (C)  f(x) > 0
      (D)  6 < f(x) < 12

I used a graphic calc to find the answer as D but can someone provide a mathematical solution to this question

Comment: are you missing information about the range of possible values of x? if you  check, f(0) = 2 does not satisfy (D)

Comment: Is  (C) indeed $f(x) >0$? Since then (C) is in each other case also true.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it is $x^2$ not $x2$, so the first gives $$(x+\frac{3}{2})^2<\frac{1}{4}$$ and thus $-2<x<-1$, and $f(-1)=6$, $f(-2)=12$

Comment: So, we know two values of $f$ which lie outside the domain of $f$.

Answer (score 1):

Considering $x^2 + 3x + 2=0$, the solutions are $x=-2$ and $x=-1$. So,$x^2 + 3x + 2<0$ if $-2<x<-1$.

Now compute $f(-2)$ and $f(-1)$ to get  the range of the function $f(x)=x^2 - 3x + 2$

You can do this directly since if $f(x)=x^2 - 3x + 2$, its derivative $f'(x)=2x-3$ cancels for $x=\frac 32$ that is to say outside the range $[-2,-1]$ we are considering. So, over this range $f'(x)<0$ and only bounds need to be considered.

Comment: Yes, because $f'(x)=2x-3$ cancels for $x=\frac 32$ which is outside the range and then, in $[-2,-1]$, $f(x)$ is strictly decreasing. Is this clear to you now ? If not, just post. Cheers.

Comment: @Hetebrij. You are right and I shall edit my post to make it clearer.